Concatenate matrices and vectors in Python
I am a MATLAB user, and trying to convert a rotation/translation code into Python:
from functools import reduce
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
from math import pi as PI 
from math import sin as sin 
from math import cos as cos 

# plt.close('all')

#   coordinate in old system
x0 = np.array([ [10], 
                [5], 
                [0],])

x = x0


# translation
# origin of old coordinate system in relative to the new coordinate system 
T = np.array([  [10],
                [0],
                [0]])


## rotation
# rotate alpha, beta, and gamme about x-axis, y-axis, and z- axis,
# respectively, in relative to the new coordinate system

alpha = 0
beta  = 0
gamma = PI/2

# rotation matrices
Rx = np.array([ [1,           0,              0],
                [0,   cos(alpha),   -sin(alpha)], 
                [0,   sin(alpha),    cos(alpha)] ])

Ry = np.array([ [cos(beta),     0,       sin(beta)], 
                [0,             1,               0],
                [-sin(beta),    0,       cos(beta)]])

Rz = np.array([ [cos(gamma),   -sin(gamma),   0],
                [sin(gamma),    cos(gamma),   0], 
                [0,                      0,   1] ])

# R = Rz*Ry*Rx
R = reduce(np.dot, [Rz, Ry, Rx])

RT = np.array([ [R,       T],
                [0, 0, 0, 1]])

The last line trying to create a homogeneous 4X4 matrix RT by stacking a 3X3 rotation matrix R and 3X1 translation vector T. The [0,0,0,1] at the bottom of the matrix is just to turn the transformation matrix RT into a homogeneous format.
The code have problem stack the R, T and [0,0,0,1] together. I am trying understand what is the proper way to do it? Thanks!!

Try
intermediate = np.concatenate((R, T.T), axis=1)
RT = np.concatenate((intermediate, np.array([0, 0, 0, 1])), axis=0)

